# Pandas: Check if a dataframe exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have significantly large volume of "Raw data" stored in pickle files. At first I have to read/load them in pandas dataframe. Afterwards I do some analysis, update something, analyze again and so on.

Every time I run the code, it reads the raw data from the pickle files. This takes quite some time that I want to avoid. One dirty solution is, I load the files once and then comment out the reading section. Of course I remain careful not to `%reset` the namespace.

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.read_pickle('MyFile_1.pkl')
df_2 = pd.read_pickle('MyFile_2.pkl')
df_3 = pd.read_pickle('MyFile_3.pkl')

Do some work on the loaded data.....
```

Is there some smart way to do it? Something like

```
if Myfile_1.pkl is NOT loaded:
   df_1 = pd.read_pickle('MyFile_1.pkl')
```

Comment: If you are using same names, you can check in `globals()`, e.g. `if 'df_1' not in globals():df_1 = pd.read_pickle('MyFile_1.pkl')`

Comment: perhaps consider working with smaller test datasets that mimic the actual data while you are developing your code. Once everything is complete and working on the test data then run the code on the full datasets